# The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin,for plugin Workmanager in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I wanted to run a background process in flutter.I used the code in https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager#-example-tab- and added the dependency required in pubspec.yaml file.

But I am getting "The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin".The detail of the  which I am sharing in the screenshot below(2 images):

[image: Output-screenshot 1]

[image: Output-screenshot 2]

I tried checking my gradle.properties file as suggested in some posts.But useAndroidX,enableJetifier were set "true".The details of gradle.properties is below:

android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true

This is my flutter doctor -v details:
[image: flutter doctor -v screenshot]

The flutter build --verbose

[image: flutter build --verbose]

Answer (score 1):

I recently got this error, while using `cloud_firestore` plugin.

Since, Starting from Flutter v1.12.13, new projects created with flutter use AndroidX by default, therefore that didn't solve my problem.

After several times doing `Pub get` with any versions of plugin,
I figured all you have to do is:

• Go to `android/app/build.gradle` of your Flutter project, and

• Set `minSdkVersion 21`

Now, on running `flutter build apk`, the error should go away.

Comment: I did all that and it wasn't enough. I also had to open the Android project on Android studio and update the gradle plugin and gradle versions as prompted. After that and all the sync, I went back to the flutter project and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to migrate to AndroidX maybe
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration
refer this link, please

Comment: Yeah,it did help.Actually I tried that yesterday also,but somehow I did a bit different today and though the sync with gradle file option from the file menu was grayed out it still ran when I clicked on it.Seems today is a good day for me ,because yesterday,the whole day nothinn worked.Thanks for your response

Comment: Ok great @chethan CV